# Strange data corruption in Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, raid5, data-recovery

I've got a server running Windows Server 2012 R2, OS is in RAID 0 (2x WD Black 500 GB), Data is in RAID 5 (4x WD Red 1 TB) and primarily holds thousands of documents. Since the past week or so we've realized that many files on the Data array have become corrupt in a weird way, and of course no one set up a scheduled backup. The only pattern I can find in the corruption is that the majority of the files affected were created or modified from the beginning of 2015 to now, although there are some new files that are fine.

For example, if I open `invoice.docx` in Word it of course tells me the file is corrupt and can't open. Opening the file in notepad or any hex editor reveals data that doesn't belong, but has come from somewhere else on the volume. One file might contain a directory listing with filenames and timestamps, another contained what looked like printer drivers for OS X. It's almost like some bits and pieces on the disk(s) shifted and the $MFT remained the same.

Windows reports no errors, `chkdsk` says everything is fine, and the RAID controller hasn't detected anything amiss either. As far as the server is concerned these files are correct, although TestDisk says $MFT and the mirror are bad but doesn't go into detail. What are my options here and what are some possibilities for how this was caused? Right now I'm running a signature based data recovery in PhotoRec because from what I understand the data is probably still there, so even without the metadata if we can at least scan by sector instead of filesystem it will be better than nothing.

I don't normally do server support but nevertheless this issue has been passed down to me. Apologies if I sound like an idiot, I've done a lot of research in the past few days on file system anatomy, RAID 5, and data corruption, and it's probably easy to miss something when overloaded like this.

Answer (score 1):

If you got a corruption, that mean one of your hard drive ins't flagged defect, but it's, then you are out of luck without backup (and yes, such happen from time to time, updating raid adapter firmware help to prevent that)

One thing that can happen, do you have a crypolocker virus running on a computer ? but usually he rename the file extension.

If it's not a virus;

1 - Is it a DC ?:

.. Yes, and it's alone : promote another one to copy your AD **fast**. *By fast, I mean even if you dont have another server, install virtualbox on any computer, use a demo license of 2012 and go right now even if it run on a secretary computer. I saved an AD that way on a customer, you just de-promote it later*

.. Yes, and other got GC : Be ready to **close it fast** before it sync corruption.

2 - Copy everything you can while the array work.

3 - Kill the server for good and dont re-use the controller/disk please

Comment: do you have corruption on the OS (RAID 1) or the DATA (RAID 5)?  After backing up to prevent further damage (which it sounds you already have, good!) Does anyone know how to check what drives etc may be failing if the drives are failing?  Might be a matter of getting a replacement drive ready to swap?  But it may be more than that with the parity of the RAID 5 and/or raid card, batter backup?  Are you using onboard software RAID?  apparently that is not good.  system details may be handy here.  maybe google corrupt docx?

Answer (score 0):

First off as EVERYONE will tell you:
BACKUP!!!!!

RAID isn't a backup.

Either way... you probably mean the OS is raid 1 not 0.  Raid 1 is mirror.

Personally I wouldn't use raid 5. (I personally prefer raid 1 or raid 1+0 (raid 10)).  Especially if your raid card isn't very good and doesn't have cache or even a battery cache backup attached.  I use a good ups backup on the server... but I use raid 1..not 5 or so.

State your raid hardware i.e. model number of the card and bios version... that may be the problem also.

If your getting constant corruption... you better start making a back up NOW before you start losing it all!  If anything copy all your important data (the raid 5) to a external drive or something.

Your data could also be getting corrupt through the network?  Do you have high RFI around?  I.e. welding machines near the server etc?

WIFI network?  That could also be it.

Drive(s) may be failing?

Comment: Yeah, once this is resolved I'm setting up proper backups, among other things that aren't quite right. The guy who built the server and usually does the maintenance apparently forgot to do this. So, there's a reason he's not the one handling this problem. The raid card is onboard, Intel chipset C222. First thing I did was mirror the volume sector by sector and make multiple copies, so if the damage is still ongoing we've got something.

Comment: might want to provide more detailed specs on the system...may help.